# Parse arbitrary bytes input

Tags: solidity, contract-design, bytes

A function recives bytes as input:

`function foo (bytes data)`

How do I parse that into individual byte32 chunks?

`function foo (bytes data) returns (bytes32[])`

My goal is to understand how to handle the Token function:

`receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data)`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the `bytes` with an increment of `32`:

```
function foo(bytes memory data) internal pure returns (bytes32[] memory output) {
    require(data.length % 32 == 0);
    output = new bytes32[](data.length / 32);
    for (uint256 i = 32; i <= output.length * 32; i += 32) {
        assembly {mstore(add(output, i), mload(add(data, i)))}
    }
}
```